# How to find column name in table

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, dbeaver

I'm trying to find a column in a very big table in ORACLE SQL Developer, its really difficult to find it visually.

Is there any easy way to find the column in the table?

For example, in DBeaver its just <kbd>Tab</kbd> and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd>

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Oracle has an awesome [data dictionary](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/datadict.htm). Most of the time it will be even faster to write a query that accesses some of its views than use IDE features.

You can get columns from view `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS`.

```
SELECT *
FROM   ALL_TAB_COLUMNS
WHERE  TABLE_NAME = :your_table_name
AND    COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%YOUR_SEARCH_STRING%'
```

As for SQL Developer, you can open table from your connections tree, go to *Columns* tab and just use *Edit -> Find (Ctrl/Cmd + F)*. Works for me in 4.0.2.15.

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer writing a query is more faster compared to IDE provided buttons and clicks.

If so this would work out.

Use the following.

You can try this via **SQL tool** that is used by you

```
select table_name from all_tab_columns where column_name = 'PICK_COLUMN';
```

Or if you have **DBA privileges**,

```
select table_name from dba_tab_columns where column_name = 'PICK_COLUMN';
```

But if you are not sure about the column names you can add `LIKE` statements to current query.

Eg:

```
select table_name from all_tab_columns where column_name LIKE '%PICK_COLUMN%';
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no search feature in the SQL Developer data grids for finding/navigating to a specific Column, but I'll add that as a feature request.

You may find the Single Record View handy for browsing very WIDE records.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a link or status update to your feature request? I would appreciate a feature to quickly find or highlight a column in large tables, too.

Answer (score 1):

On toolbar, Click View->Find DB Object
Now select the connection, the type and which column the value has to be found in. (NAME,TYPE AND USAGE(ALL))
The tables are displayed, select the table to view the columns having the field you are searching for.

[image: dbeaver search]

Answer (score 0):

Right click on column header in the data grid, then you have a menu Columns where you can filter columns you want to display

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer, but still, i can't search the column name / substring in column name.

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click on your connection name.
2. Then click "Find DB Object" on the context menu.
3. It will take you to a textbox. Write your column name
4. And check the box with "Columns".
5. Then press "enter" or click on "Go".

Then sqldeveloper will search your column and will show you the result [ column name with table name].